# Javascript Word To Binary to Array of Bits

Tags: javascript

I have this code  // Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/7buscnhw/

```
// Word to bits func
function dec2bin(dec) {
  return (dec >>> 0).toString(2);
}
// binary to bit array
function bin2array(bin) {
    let Bitarr = []
    for(let i = 0; i < bin.length; ++i)
  Bitarr[i] = (bin >> i) & 1;
  return Bitarr;
}


R24011 = dec2bin(10);

Bits = bin2array(R24011);

msg = {
    R24011: R24011,
    BitArray: Bits
}
console.log(msg)
```

It correctly outputs 1010 for Ten in binary, but when I push it to an array I get [0,1,0,0]

I'm sure it'll be something stupid but I cant figure out what I've done wrong.

Comment: _"but when I push it to an array"_ - where do you do this? --- Edit: ah I see. It's the result of `bin2array(dec2bin(10))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass `bin` (which is a string `"1010"`) and apply `>>` to it, which makes Javascript convert it to a number *in base 10*, resulting in `1010` (one thousand and ten), which is binary `1111110010`. Then, you convert that one to binary once again, using only four bits and in reversed order, which results in `[0,1,0,0]`

If you want to convert a number (not a string) to an array bits (and avoid built-ins), you can do that like this:

```js
function num2bits(number) {
    let Bitarr = []

    while (number) {
        Bitarr.unshift(number & 1);
        number >>= 1
    }
    return Bitarr;
}

console.log(num2bits(10))
```

With built-ins this is as simple as

```
bits = [...yourNumber.toString(2)].map(Number)
```

Comment: This gets its done. is there an easy way to reverse the array direction. for example, Bitarr[0] to be the 1/0  and Bitarr[3] to be 8. Ah nevermind ofc there is .reverse

Answer (score 2):

You can directly use spread syntax to convert the binary string to an array.

```js
function dec2bin(dec) {
  return (dec >>> 0).toString(2);
}
function bin2array(bin) {
  return [...bin].map(Number);
}
R24011 = dec2bin(10);
console.log(R24011)
Bits = bin2array(R24011);
console.log(Bits)
```